# Is "she is ill or otherwise prevented" correct English?

Tags: grammar

I basically want to say that someone is ill or there is something else preventing them from coming. Is it the correct way of saying it?

Comment: Question about proof-reading is off-topic in this site. Please edit your question about what things did you want to focus ( What did you confused about?) . You can see more information here: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/alternative-websites-for-proofreading

Comment: She is [indisposed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/indisposed). You don't have to go into detail (or explain that there might be a different reason). You can add "... and she sends her apologies".

Comment: Voting to close as unclear; please use the "Edit" button to tell a bit more. Please give the entire sentence you're proposing, and explain why you have concerns about it. If it's "She is ill or otherwise prevented," as in the title, it would normally include "... from coming," but this can be left out if context makes it clear. There are also better options.